# How to merge many data frames to only one

Tags: python, json, pandas, deep-learning, operating-system

I have directory that has many folders inside each folder has (`images folder & labels text`) and I want to combine them to one dataframe file by concatnating folders name with images name to make them uinque names .
The structuer of my directory like below  :

```
$ tree
.
├── sample
│   ├---- folder_1 ----|-- -- train.jsonl
|   |                  |----- imgs 
|   |                  |          └───├── 0.png
|   |                  |              └── 1.png
|   |                  |              └── 2.png
|   |                  |              └── 3.png
..  ..                ...               ...
|   |                  |              └── n.png
│   ├---- folder_2 ----|-- -- train.jsonl
|   |                  |----- imgs 
|   |                  |          └───├── 0.png
|   |                  |              └── 1.png
|   |                  |              └── 2.png
|   |                  |              └── 3.png
..  ..                ...               ...
|   |                  |              └── n.png
│   ├---- folder_3 ----|-- -- train.jsonl
|   |                  |----- imgs 
|   |                  |          └───├── 0.png
|   |                  |              └── 1.png
|   |                  |              └── 2.png
|   |                  |              └── 3.png
..  ..                ...               ...
|   |                  |              └── n.png
```

In each folder, the `train.jsonl` file contains the image name and the corresponding text for example in `folder_1`

```
{"file_name": "0.png", "text": "Hello"}
{"file_name": "1.png", "text": "there"}
```

In others as well `folder_2` :

```
{"file_name": "0.png", "text": "Hi"}
{"file_name": "1.png", "text": "there from the second dir"}
```

....

What I want to update `file_name` path by reading those json lines with pandas or python and concatenating parent directories with image name :

Now after the update by [**@RAI**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75701948/how-to-merge-many-data-frames-to-only-one/75702105#75702105)

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['file_name', 'text'])

# Traverse the directory recursively
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('sample'):
    for file in files:
        if file == 'train.jsonl':
            df_temp = pd.read_json(os.path.join(root, file), lines=True)
            df_temp['file_name'] = os.path.join(root, 'imgs', df_temp['file_name'])

            df = df.append(df_temp, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Get this issue :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merage_files.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(os.path.join(root, 'imgs', df_temp['file_name']))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py", line 90, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', a, *p)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/genericpath.py", line 152, in _check_arg_types
    raise TypeError(f'{funcname}() argument must be str, bytes, or '
TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'Series'
```

So the expected df should look like this:

```
       file_name                    text
0  sample/folder_1/0.png           Hello
1  sample/folder_1/1.png           there
2  sample/folder_2/0.png            Hi
3  sample/folder_2/1.png         there from the second dir
  ..........                          ........
```

To make them unique and we can loop through one data frame file combine all of them

Answer (score 0):

The error message says:

`TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'Series'`

because `df_temp['file_name']` is of type `pd.Series`. Instead, use the `apply()` method, by replacing the line:

`df_temp['file_name'] = os.path.join(root, 'imgs', df_temp['file_name'])`

by:

`df_temp['file_name'] = df_temp['file_name'].apply(lambda x: os.path.join(root, 'imgs', x))`